# Facebook like comment return URL, that gives 404 on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook, url, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I have video blog www.gofreestyle.cz

In post, there is Facebook Like button, which can share the like with some comment.

When I click Like and add a comment, it appears on my Facebook wall. BUT!

It returns URL like: http://www.gofreestyle.cz/style-nike-oficialne-odhalil-boty-z-navratu-do-budoucnosti-s-automatickym-utahovanim-tkanicek-tak-aspon-ty-boty/?fb_action_ids=10208382997121829&fb_action_types=og.likes

That part: ?fb_action_ids=10208382997121829&fb_action_types=og.likes causes, that the URL is 404, not working.

In Facebook activity, there is normal URL http://www.gofreestyle.cz/style-nike-oficialne-odhalil-boty-z-navratu-do-budoucnosti-s-automatickym-utahovanim-tkanicek-tak-aspon-ty-boty/ which works normally...

Can anybody help me, how to fix it?

I use Wordpress permalink /%postname%/ ... may be .htacces?

It generally not works with any URL from some plugins, which puts some part after the URL link /?reembed_url_ and so on and on...

Comment: why dont you use wordpress plugins like 'like box' etc?

Comment: It is no plugin, its Facebook generated Like button... If you do LIKE, and comment, the url on the Facebook wall is like that... If I use normal permalink like go freestyle.cz/?page=1654 and no using hatches to make friendly URLS, the url with the Facebook part works...

Comment: oh, why I don't use... OK, Ill try it...

Comment: Ou, I looked at this plugin... It doesn't matter... I can make this with Facebook developer page... It is not the problem.. Problem is with the permalinks in Wordpress

Comment: you are using sheduled publish or publish immediatly .?

Comment: Immediatly... I think it can by problem with server, which is nginx/1.6.1

Comment: may be but i dont think so.. that facebook type things some time annoy you alot. solution is always simple.

Comment: check this one http://www.passwordincorrect.com/issue-with-sharing-wordpress-posts-to-facebook/

Comment: But I post it immediately... every post.. I have no drafts, or scheduled posts...